# trying to redirect ONLY the site root, 404 re-routed as well

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-404, httpd.conf

I'm trying to redirect [www.oldsite.com](http://www.oldsite.com) to [www.newsite.com](http://www.newsite.com), but ONLY for the root directory.

oldsite.com/real/thing will still exist and should be world-readable at its original location, but going directly to oldsite.com or [www.oldsite.com](http://www.oldsite.com) should redirect to [www.newsite.com](http://www.newsite.com)

I tried to do this with a simple

```
Redirect / https://www.newsite.com
```

in `httpd.conf`, but that is too aggressive and won't result in a proper display of oldsite.com/real/thing

I can do a meta refresh in `index.html` at the site root, but that is apparently frowned upon.  It does seem to be the most logical of choices, because I suppose what I really mean is that if you somehow would have gotten to the regular index page, go to the new place instead.

What ultimately seems to work is this code, in an `.htaccess` file at the site root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ https://www.newsite.com [R=301,L]
```

It does exactly what I want it to do, but I do have a question.

oldsite.com/real/thing can be navigated to perfectly, but oldsite.com/foo/oops/not/here which does not exist and I would expect to pop a standard 404 also redirects to [www.newsite.com](http://www.newsite.com)

This is not necessarily a bad thing, and probably what I actually want to happen, but I was under the impression that the ^$ in the RewriteRule would match only the root destination.  So, what's going on?

How would I re-route the 404s elsewhere if I wanted to?

And, I suppose, does my solution seem reasonable?  Suggestions for making it safer/better/smarter?

Thanks!

EDIT: This is the `ErrorDocument` line from the `httpd.config` file...nothing special!

```
ErrorDocument 404 "Page not found."
```

Comment: That rule _should_ work. Presumably oldsite and newsite reside on different servers? What other directives do you have? You may have a conflict. Also make sure your browser cache is clear. Since if you have experimented with (erroneous) 301s then they will have been cached by the browser.

Comment: Yes, oldsite and newsite are on different servers. I do have some rules forcing the URL to use https and pushing oldsite.com to www.oldsite.com, but without the .htaccess file in place, oldsite.com/foo results in a standard 404 error picked up by the ErrorDocument line in http.conf, as expected. There are several virtual hosts on the server, so that could be a complicating factor. Any tips on what to look for? Also, yes, the browser issue had been a problem, so I fired up Edge and configured it to forget everything every time I close the program.

Comment: You have no other rewrites in `.htaccess`? So your URLs map directly to actual files? It's not clear how other vHosts could affect this without seeing your server config.

Comment: What is your `ErrorDocument` line?

Comment: There's nothing else in the `.htaccess` file. The `httpd.config` has some aliases and such, but the key thing seems to be that 404 responds normally when the .htaccess file is completely removed. Maybe I should take out the `L` to allow further processing to continue? I'll add the `ErrorDocument` line up in the original post, but it's nothing special.

Comment: "Maybe I should take out the `L`" - You should keep the `L` flag. You don't want "further processing to continue." However, that makes no difference if you have no other mod_rewrite directives in this `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Oh, OK, I thought it meant it would prevent processing of stuff in `httpd.config` as well. The lines I posted above are the only two in the `.htaccess` file.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've found an answer to my own question.

If I add the `ErrorDocument` line to the top of the `.htaccess` file, it seems to intercept the bad URL before the rewrite.

So, rather than relying on the line in `httpd.config` and not knowing exactly in what order things are will be processed, I'll have a tiny bit of code duplication.

That seems like a reasonable price to pay.

Meanwhile, the original `ErrorDocument` line is working fine for other virtual hosts on the server.